# Reserving gpu memory tensorflow before loading data

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to reserve GPU memory before the graph is built and run in tensorflow?

I have a slow data loading that needs to be done before creating the graph and running it. I am sharing a GPU cluster so sometimes other people would use the GPU that I have designated before I'm done loading the data and the program will encounter OOM error.

Comment: Why not construct the graph beforehand. Having the `queue.dequeue_many` operation, you do not need to generate data first. Just start with the graph and initialization of the graph.

Comment: @Patwie I considered this but I'm modifying someone else's code and modifying the graph construction may introduce errors. In my case, putting the loading of data first is easier to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device memory is reserved when you instantiate a `tf.Session`.

If you need to reserve device memory early on, you could start by creating a session, and then proceed normally to construct your graph. Although it is common in "raw" tensorflow to create the graph first then instantiate a session, it is nonetheless allowed to proceed differently, and it is actually common in the Keras world where one would often start a script with

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(sess)
...
```